# install FB CTF from scratch

Tags: nginx, hhvm, hacklang

Can I get how to install FBCTF Mannually. which all software is needed for that. ***from the scratch*** including server software for `hack`,  `nginx` and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB CTF in an open source hackathon conducting platform which is specially coded for Ubuntu v14.04LTE TRUSTY in `hacklang`(Language Derived from PHP, actually not PHP). It itself set up required environment.

`Download FBCTF from www.github.com/facebook.com/fbctf` and extracted into home folder as `/home/<username>/fbctf/`

All code of Project is there on `/fbctf/src/`

Line no 49 to 59 :: file `/fbctf/extra/provision.sh`

```
 MODE="dev"                            # dev / prod   ///PREFERRABLY PROD
 NOREPOMODE=false    
 TYPE="self"                           # CTF ITSELF PRODUCE ITS CERTIFICATE
 KEYFILE="none"
 CERTFILE="none"
 DOMAIN="localhost"                    # DOMAIN YOU ARE GOING TO INSTALL
 EMAIL="none"
 CODE_PATH="/home/<username>/fbctf"    # by default `/vagrant` change it to where the downloaded code is present     
 CTF_PATH="/var/www/fbctf"             # by default it is /var/www/  change it if u need to install to some other destination. (Make sure that this path is access able to nginx and hhvm) 
 HHVM_CONFIG_PATH="/etc/hhvm/server.ini"
```

this can be done by passing parameter to file.
`----------------------------------------------------------------------------`

ON COMMAND PROMPT :

```
 cd fbctf
 ./extra/provision.sh prod `pwd`
```

it will start installing software of its own.
including

[+] GIT

[+] CURL

[+] English Language pack

[+] Python setup tools

[+] memcached

[+] mysql

[+] php5

[+] HHVM (VIRTUAL MACHINE TO PROCESS HACKLANG)

[+] PHP COMPOSER (TO SOLVE PHP DEPENDANCY DATA)

[+] NPM (NODE JS PACKAGE MANAGER)

[+] NODEJS-Legasy

[+] RUN GRUNT

[+] NGINX   (LOAD BALANCER)

[+] UNISON(if not setting up in vagrant; u can comment this by using **#**; #install_unison used to sync vagrant and host data live)

[+] MAKE DATABASE READY.

Possibly if there is no errore and All Sync are set up perfectly, then work on `localhost`

POSSIBLE ERRORS.

Usually NGinx AND APACHE GO FOR PORT 80 (UNLESS HTTPS; WHICH IS 443) AND COLASHING OCCOURS.
SO CHANGE APACHE PORT 80 TO SOME OTHER SUCH AS 8080 AND SHUT DOWM APACHE

`sudo service apache2 stop`                                              [OK]

`sudo service nginx restart`                                             [OK]